# order groups returned by XQuery FLWOR group by clause in document order

Tags: xquery, xslt-3.0, xquery-3.1

Coming from an XSLT background I sometimes struggle to find the XQuery equivalent of some XSLT approach I am used to. This question is about how to order groups in document order, which XSLT 2/3 seems to do automatically while with XQuery the order seems to be undefined.

In more detail: with grouping in XSLT 3 (or 2 as well) I am used to (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#order-of-groups) getting the groups returned in "order of first appearance", that is, for instance, when I group some child elements of an element, the ordering of groups is determined by the document order of the first item in each group. This doesn't seem to be the case in XQuery, where https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by says: "The order in which tuples appear in the post-grouping tuple stream is implementation-dependent.".

The question in short is: if

```
              for $city in city
              group by $country := $city/@country
              return ...
```

doesn't guarantee me any order in XQuery, is using

```
              for $city at $pos in city
              group by $country := $city/@country
              order by $pos[1]
              return ...
```

instead the right way to have the "order of first appearance" in XQuery, like XSLT does it by default?

The background: in a simple example (taken from the XSLT 3 spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#grouping-examples) the `city` elements in

```
<cities>
  <city name="Milano"  country="Italia"      pop="5"/>
  <city name="Paris"   country="France"      pop="7"/>
  <city name="München" country="Deutschland" pop="4"/>
  <city name="Lyon"    country="France"      pop="2"/>
  <city name="Venezia" country="Italia"      pop="1"/>
</cities>
```

have to be grouped by the `@country` attribute value to sum up the `@pop` population value for each country.

A compact XSLT 3 way to do that is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="cities">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Country</th>
                  <th>Cities</th>
                  <th>Population</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="city" group-by="@country">
                  <tr>
                      <td>{ current-grouping-key() }</td>
                      <td>
                          <xsl:value-of select="sort(current-group()/@name)" separator=", "/>
                      </td>
                      <td>{ sum(current-group()/@pop) }</td>
                  </tr>
              </xsl:for-each-group>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I think with a compliant XSLT 3 implementation I am guaranteed to get the result in the order (`Italia`, `France`, `Deutschland`) from the input:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Country</th>
         <th>Cities</th>
         <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Italia</td>
         <td>Milano, Venezia</td>
         <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>France</td>
         <td>Lyon, Paris</td>
         <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Deutschland</td>
         <td>München</td>
         <td>4</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

With XQuery however I think I am not guaranteed any specific order, with

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'html';
declare option output:html-version '5';

    cities/<table>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Country</th>
                      <th>Cities</th>
                      <th>Population</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  {
                      for $city in city
                      group by $country := $city/@country
                      return
                          <tr>
                              <td>{ $country }</td>
                              <td>{ string-join( sort($city/@name/string()), ', ') }</td>
                              <td>{ sum($city/@pop) }</td>
                          </tr>
                  }
              </tbody>
          </table>
```

Saxon at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV7 gives me the result as

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Country</th>
         <th>Cities</th>
         <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Deutschland</td>
         <td>München</td>
         <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Italia</td>
         <td>Milano, Venezia</td>
         <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>France</td>
         <td>Lyon, Paris</td>
         <td>9</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What is the right way to ensure the order is taken from the "order of first appearance" in XQuery, is using

```
              for $city at $pos in city
              group by $country := $city/@country
              order by $pos[1]
              return
                  <tr>
                      <td>{ $country }</td>
                      <td>{ string-join( sort($city/@name/string()), ', ') }</td>
                      <td>{ sum($city/@pop) }</td>
                  </tr>
```

the right or easiest, most compact way?

Seems to do the job at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV7/1 but I would like opinions whether there is a different way, more idiomatic way for XQuery.

Comment: "Order of first appearance" is only the same as document order if the grouping population is in document order, which of course will often be the case. There are two issues here: the order of the groups, and the order of items within each group. The difference between XQuery and XSLT here is a classic example of XQuery taking a more data-oriented approach and XSLT taking a more document-oriented approach.

Comment: @MichaelKay, the order of items in a group is a different issue I intentionally didn't include in the question as, on one hand, the sample does only aggregate, and on the other hand I think the XQuery spec with "If ordering mode is ordered, the values derived from individual tuples are concatenated in a way that preserves the order of the pre-grouping tuple stream; otherwise the ordering of these values is implementation-dependent" gives me a clue to achieve in XQuery with the ordering mode what I would get by XSLT.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I agree that the "'order of first appearance' is only the same as the document order if the population is in document order", so, right, the question is about maintaining that document order for the groups with a population in document order, like the `city` elements of the sample.